# linking ng-view in rendering pages

Tags: angularjs

I am using intellij and it created a template for me. I am trying to use:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

to direct my pages. However currently the default index page in rendering. This is just my attempt to figure out how things are connecting.

configuration.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: "app/pages/mainPage/mainPage.html",
        controller:"mainPageController"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
});
```

mainPage.html

```
    <div>

    <h2>Hello World</h2>

    </div>
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="pages/mainPage/mainPageController.js"></script>
  <script src="configuration.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]);
```

view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

//.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
//  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
//    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
//    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
//  });
//}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

view2.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute'])

//.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
//  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
//    templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
//    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
//  });
//}])

.controller('View2Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

I am trying to render mainPage.html and handle all the redirects in one file i.e configuration.js

Comment: What is in `view1.js`? Are routes configured in those files also? Problem description is not very clear

Comment: @charlietfl please see update

Comment: need to un-comment those configs and routes so you can access them.

Comment: No, I can put them in the configuration.js file. I want to render mainPage.html when '/' . However right now index.html is displaying

Comment: index.html will always be there. your route templates should show up inside `ng-view`. Set `otherwise` to `/` just to get started and should see `mainPage.html` inside that container

Comment: And if it's not there look in browser dev tools network to see if request path for template ajax request is failing

Comment: That is what is so confusing, I did that. In chrome dev tools it just says: Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!

Comment: i haven't used `$location` in a long time... i usually use a different router Not complicated issue though. In `<head>` try `<base href="/">` if page is at root of site

Comment: No that didn't work. I am really confused on why this simple thing is not working. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I just recreated the whole project and got it working. Not sure what was going on with the other one.